# Can't add/change resource in solrcloud

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I'm beginner with solrand I have some difficulties to manipulate resources. 
In fact, I m using solr 7.2. in cloud mode using zookeper:

1/ I create collection named films

2/ I wanted to add synonyms file  called "syns.txt" so I added it into "server/solr/configsets/_default/conf/"

3/ I execute the following command line

curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "replace-field-type":{
     "name":"*text*",
     "class":"solr.TextField",
     "positionIncrementGap":"100",
     "analyzer":{
        "charFilters":[{
           "class":"solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory",
           "replacement":"$1$1",
           "pattern":"([a-zA-Z])\\1+" }],
        "tokenizer":{
           "class":"solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory" },
        "filters":[{
           "class":"solr.StopFilterFactory",
           "ignoreCase":true,
            "words":"stopwords.txt"
           },
           { "class":"solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" },
           { "class":"solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" },
           { "class":"solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory" },
           { "class":"solr.SynonymFilterFactory","synonyms":"syns.txt"}
           ]}},
   "replace-field" : {
      "name":"*text*",
      "type":"*text*",
      "stored":true,
      "multiValued":true,
      "indexed":true
      }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/films/schema

the problem is that I get Can't find resource 'syns.txt' in classpath or '/configs/films' cwd=/home/solr-7.2.1/server\nCan't find resource 'syns.txt' in classpath or '/configs/films'.

I even change in server/solr/configsets/_default/conf/synonyms.txt and I didn't see the result in the synonyms.xt in the admin console.
Can anyone help me please?

[image]

But I even change in server/solr/configsets/_default/conf/ contains:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try org.apache.solr.rest.schema.analysis.ManagedWordSetResource

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary \
'{"class":"org.apache.solr.rest.schema.analysis.ManagedWordSetResource"}' \
"http://localhost:8983/solr/films/schema/analysis/synonyms/syns"
```